# Power BI/DAX - compare single column value across rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

(I'm specifically seeking a DAX solution) Given the below sample table, I want to get a count of how many IDs have differing levels for type=A and type=B (ignore any other types).  In this case, the count would be 1 since ID 123 has differing levels for types A and B.

| ID | Type | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 2 |
| 123 | B | 1 |
| 123 | C | 2 |
| 987 | A | 3 |
| 987 | B | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filtered the main table for types A and B to create a summary table by ID, by calculating the maximum  level for types A and B separately for each ID. This is necessary because your example doesn't specify multiple levels per type per ID, but if that's a possibility, with MAX  you get a distinct level to compare.

```
   IDsWithDifferingLevels = 
    VAR FilteredTable = 
        FILTER(
            'YourTableName',
            'YourTableName'[Type] = "A" || 'YourTableName'[Type] = "B"
        )
    
    VAR SummaryTable = 
        SUMMARIZE(
            FilteredTable,
            'YourTableName'[ID],
            "LevelA", CALCULATE(MAX('YourTableName'[Level]), 'YourTableName'[Type] = "A"),
            "LevelB", CALCULATE(MAX('YourTableName'[Level]), 'YourTableName'[Type] = "B")
        )
    
    VAR DifferingLevelsCount = 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(
                    SummaryTable,
                    [LevelA] <> [LevelB]
                )
            )
        )
    
    RETURN
        DifferingLevelsCount
```

[image]